# Evaluating the cumulative multivariate hypergeometric distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Suppose there are 5 black, 10 white, and 15 red marbles in an urn for a total of $N=5+10+15$ marbles. You randomly draw $n=6$ marbles without replacement. The probability that you pick exactly two of each color is given by the multivariate hypergeometric function.

$$\Pr[1\textrm{ black},1\textrm{ white},2\textrm{ red}]=\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{10}{1}\binom{15}{1}}{\binom{30}{6}}
$$

How is possible instead in Mathematica to get the probability to draw **at least** 1 black, 1 white and 2 red?

$$\Pr[\textrm{ black} \geq 2, \textrm{ white} \geq 2, \textrm{ red}\geq 2]
$$

Comment: If you draw 6 marbles and you want the probability of at least two of each, this can only happen by having exactly two of each.

Comment: [An urn contains 12 red balls, 23 blue balls, and 9 green balls](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution.html) see on **Applications**

Comment: I came up with this solution:
    \[ScriptCapitalD] = MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[5, {12, 23, 9}];
    Probability[
 x > 1 \[And] y > 1 \[And] 
  z > 0, {x, y, z} \[Distributed] \[ScriptCapitalD]]